# Merge two Google play/apps accounts into one list

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to merge two Google play accounts into one or at least have two common lists?

I have two Google accounts I routinely use on Android. One for business and one personal. That said I wasn't always consistent in my usage. Now when I add a new android device, I need to pick through both accounts to load the android apps I consider essential.

I'd be open to a onetime merge, even if it involves exporting and reimporting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge two separate Google Play accounts per Google ([link to Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304?hl=en)).  Apps purchased on one account cannot be transferred to another account, etc:

*It isn't currently possible to merge separate Google Accounts.*

Comment: That's quite annoying -in my case. I'm surprised with all the easy access to other Google account data this is locked.I suppose if it wasn't there would be a whole new secondary market for Google Apps...